# IIS SMTP Server is taking too much CPU

Tags: iis, monitoring, smtp, windows-server-2012, central-processing-unit

I am setting up a Windows Server 2012 with IIS for PHP/Mysql-hosting. I soon as I start the SMTP-service (from IIS 6 Manager) the CPU-percentage in Task Manager spikes.

First when I got the server, I saw how it worked, and found out that spam-bots where relaying e-mails through the server. I set the SMTP-service to only allow connections through from localhost/server-ip. And so nothing shows up in the SMTP-service logs.

Could it be possible something is still hitting my server on Port 25, and it reaches the SMTP-service which denies access but still affects CPU? How can I troubleshoot this?

[image: Task manager]

Comment: Wouldn't your firewall logs answer if something is connecting on port 25?

Comment: "IIS SMTP Server is taking too much CPU" is a statement that you've neither quantified or qualified. Just because it's using more CPU then you might expect it to doesn't mean it's using too much CPU. Where is your benchmark? Where are your comparative performance metrics?

Comment: @joeqwerty :) Well, my benchmark is my common sense that an SMTP service, not routing any e-mail, should take "almost" no CPU at all. Do you disagree?

Comment: Unless you have collected performance metrics to support that statement I would say that I do disagree. My point is that making statements without any supporting data is not the right approach to troubleshooting. Have you enabled SMTP logging and have you looked at the logs? How do you know it's not "routing" any email? It may very well be that it's still being used as an open relay, in which case you want to stop it from doing so.

Comment: If it is being used as an open relay that could explain the CPU usage, but that would throw your comment out of the window. It is being used, just not in the way that you expect or want. The assumption inferred from your question title is that SMTP isn't being used and so the CPU usage is unexpected and aberrant and my suggestion to you is to investigate and prove it. You want to know for sure that it's no longer being used as an open relay.

Comment: To more directly answer your question "How do I troubleshoot this?", start by looking at your firewall and/or router logs. Then look at the Windows firewall log, then make sure SMTP logging is enabled and look at those logs. Finally you could run netstat to look for active SMTP sessions on the server.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for more input! I wrote: "And so nothing shows up in the SMTP-service logs." As it went from being data in the logs to being no data, when I "set the SMTP-service to only allow connections through from localhost/server-ip" I was assuming no mail was routed on from the SMTP-service.

Comment: @GregAskew I looked in the logs, and the firewall are letting through requests on port 25... Approximately 3-4 requests per minute. Would that alone count for the high CPU (of in total 4 x 2GHz)?

Comment: Run the following from a command prompt: "netstat -a -n -o >c:\netstat.txt" (without the quotes). Then look for connections on Local Address on port 25. When you say you're allowing connections only from localhost, did you configure that restriction on the SMTP server or the Windows firewall? Also, can you block inbound SMTP on your network firewall/router?

Comment: @joeqwerty Wow! There are no port 25 in local Address (only ports like :56859), but foreign address has dozens of connections to different ip's on port 25. Does that mean the SMTP-server is sending out email?! Does it have a backlog somewhere it is sending, or is something on the server sending it real-time? When I shut down SMTP, there is no sign of port 25. I have the restriction in SMTP-server only. 

Addition: PID = 0 and State = TIME_WAIT

Comment: It sounds like the server is sending email outbound, so it may be that it is being used as an open relay. You're going to have to dig deeper to figure it out. Shut down your PHP/MySQL and see if the SMTP traffic stops. If it does then you know it's your PHP/MySQL that's causing it. If it doesn't then you need to keep looking.

Comment: @joeqwerty Cheers, doesn't seem to be PHP/MySQL. The netstat says its svchost.exe making the connections... So I guess it could be anything. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Try using Process Explorer to see "inside" that particular service host process to see if you can identify the specific process. You might also try Microsoft Network Monitor to see if you can identify the specific process - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. A lot of connections was made to port 25 on the server. However, after blocking them, the server still continued to send out mail. That was because the dir:

```
c:\inetpub\mailroot\queue\
```

had hundreds of thousands of mail queued up, ready to be sent. Emptying that directory, and now SMTP works as it should.